# ng-options and ng-model in object as data source

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I have a `select` which I want to fill it using `ng-options`. The source of the options is not an `array` but an `object`. So far so good.

This `select` has `ng-model` too. That's mean that when the model's property get value, the select need to change the selected `option` according the value.

The problem is that the selected `option` is always the first (the null `option) like in this demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.resourceList = {"0":"Unknown","1":"ILS","2":"USD","3":"AUD","4":"GBP","5":"JPY"};
  $scope.resources = {
    type: 3
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{resources.type}}
  <select ng-model="resources.type" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in resourceList track by key"></select>
  <button data-ng-click="resources.type = '4'">Replace</button>
</div>
```

**Update:** I was tried both of `resources.type = '4'` and `resources.type = 4`, neither of them work.

**Note:** I was read a lot of questions here with similar topic but didn't find the answer for this specific issue so, please, read the question again before you flag this as duplicate.

Comment: Try assigning the string representation of `1` - `data-ng-click="resources.type = '1'"`

Comment: @tymeJV I tried this but it's not working.

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is. When the user changes a value in the select box, then the ng-model changes. It should be a string. When you do a click on the button, the type will be assigned, but try using a string for the assignment.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon It doesn't in any way (See the update in my answer)

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected I think you are looking for a selected attribute

Comment: @SoluableNonagon this solution is for case that you do `ng-repeat` on the `option` tag. My case is to generate the `options` using `ng-options`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `track by $index` instead in your `[ng-repeat]`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.resourceList = {"0":"Unknown","1":"ILS","2":"USD","3":"AUD","4":"GBP","5":"JPY"};
  $scope.resources = {
    type: 3
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{resources.type}}
  <select ng-model="resources.type" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in resourceList track by $index"></select>
  <button data-ng-click="resources.type = '4'">Replace</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's like that it's working now BUT now the `{{resources.type}}` always render `m`.

Comment: Now, when you try to choose another option `{{resources.type}}` **always** shows `5`. It's seems that it's so close to solving. Shat missing?